# ASP MVC Web Api: how add reference to an existing entity model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

in visual studio 2013 i have created an entity data model from an existing database as a class library project (.dll).

Now in a web api project i make a reference to that entity:

```
 Right click the project > Add Reference > Browse Projects Tab and browse to the dll project.
```

I have also added the entity framework from NuGet.

Now i'd like to add a web api controller: i choose the template "Web Api 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework".
The problem is that i don't see my entity:
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you got the Entity Framework connection string in your web project, as well as the separate Class Library?

Comment: I have the connection strings in my Web.config

Comment: Normally this works so you did something wrong clearly but the information that you presented is not enough to help you solve it.